# Improve mongodb full-scan query performance: replication or sharding?

Tags: mongodb, performance, replication, sharding

We are currently facing a situation where we can't avoid doing a collection 
full-scan. We have already optimize the query and the data structure but we 
would like to go further and take full advantage of sharding and replication.

**Configuration**

```
- mongodb version 3.2
- monogo-java-driver 3.2
- storageEngine: wiredTiger
- compression level: snappy
- database size : 6GB
```

**Documents structure:**

individuals collection

```
{
    "_id": 1, 
    "name": "randomName1", 
    "info": {...}
}, 
{
    "_id": 2, 
    "name": "randomName2", 
    "info": {...}
},
[...]
{
    "_id": 15000, 
    "name": "randomName15000", 
    "info": {...}
}
```

values collection

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5804d7a41da35c2e06467911"),
    "pos": NumberLong("2090845886852"),
    "val": 
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, ... 0, 1]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5804d7a41da35c2e06467912"),
    "pos": NumberLong("2090845886857"),
    "val": 
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, ... 0, 0]
}
```

The "val" array contain an element for each individual (so the length of the array is 
up to 15000). The id of the individual is it's corresponding index in the "val" array.

**Query**

The query is to find documents from values collection where the sum of val[individual._id] is
above a specific treshold for a list of idividuals. We can't just pre-compute the sum of the 
array since the list of individuals wanted change during runtime (we may want to get the result for 
only the first 2000 individuals for example). This query use the aggregation framework.

**What we're currently doing:**

We split the query in **100-500 subqueries** and run them **5 by 5 in parallel**.

The first subquery would be the same query for documents where pos > 0 and pos < 50000, 
the second for documents where pos > 50000 and pos < 100000 ect...

We would like to be able to run more subqueries in the same time, but we're facing 
performance loss when running more than 5 on a single mongod instance.

**So the question is** : should we go for replication or for sharding (or for both) in 
order to run the maximum number of subqueries in the same time ? How could we configure
mongodb to dispatch subqueries among replica/shards as best as possible?

edit: let's assume that the query is already fully optimized !

Answer (score 1):

Replication is something used for data redundancy and high availability, so if you are trying to improve performance on a query I think we can rule that out as an option right away.

Sharding *may* be an option, but I think that the next step for you would be to post your explain for the query and see if anyone can make suggestions for improving performance.  It's possible there is some tuning your could do that you missed, or perhaps you would see performance gains by upgrading the current MongoDB server's RAM or CPU.

In short, I would suggest posting your explain before going to all the effort of sharding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe I'll post the explain in an other question, but for the moment let's assume that the query is already optimized enough, what should we do ?